# How to add a html list to a Django form field

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django-forms

I am writing this code where the users enters a name in a form field for a place and using the keyup function with ajax, it will bring data from the backend in list elements to see if the same name has already been suggested before.

[image: Django Field where the user starts typing]

Now when the user starts typing he/she will get the result like below

[image: Results from the ajax]

As you can see that it creates extra size below the field "Place name" and the reason for this is because I have created a "UL" element on this field to which the results from ajax gets attached. Although this is working fine, but what I am looking is to something like Google search results like below:

[image: Using Google Search]

Here the results are over the form and do not increase the size of the page. But I am not sure if how to do this.Apologies if this questioned has already been answered because I was unable to find it.
Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue. Try adding position relative to the parent container, and position absolute with a z-index to your 'ul'

Comment: Thanks @ShobhitSrivastava. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Cool, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS should fix it:

```
#parent_container {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10; /* more than the z-index of underlying elements */
}
```